# Public static class for sending system messages to the users - asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, static

asp.net 4.0 - C# - MSSQL 2008 r2 db

I already have a private messaging system. At certain actions i am sending them private messages. Right now i am adding them by direct insert query to the database inside code behind of asp.net page. These messages are being sent by system not user.

**For sending these messages (simply adding message to the database) i am planning to prepare a public static class. Do you think this would work ?**

Public static class will take this variables

userId of message receiving user, message title, message body

It won't do any select query to the database only insert query for sending message to the user.

There could be even 10 simultaneous call of class in an instant can this cause any problem ?
Thank you.

edit this is the class

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public static class SendMessage
{
    public static string srCommandText = "insert into mymessagestable (SenderUserId,ReceiverUserId,SentTime,Topic,Body) values(@SenderUserId,@ReceiverUserId,@SentTime,@Topic,@Body) ";

    public static bool SendMessageToDb(string srReceiverUserId, string srSenderUserId, string srSentTime, string srTopic, string srBody)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DbConnection.srConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(srCommandText, connection))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenderUserId", srSenderUserId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceiverUserId", srReceiverUserId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SentTime", srSentTime);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", srTopic);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Body", srBody);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch block until you find out what kind of exceptions you should be getting in "normal" circumstances. Maybe for those you should return false, but don't hide unusual exceptions this way, or you'll never know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue would be a violation of a unique constraint/primary key during rapid concurrent inserts.  As long as all inserts are unique, you will be fine.

Comment: but i think it is not about the class it is about database. am i correct ?

Comment: The database will handle the connections just fine.